# Marking few items from a list based on a database

Tags: php, database, data-structures

I have a list of n items(in multiple categories) like

```
Category A
      1
      2
      3
Category B
      1
      2 
      ....
```

stored in a mysql database. Corresponding to a particular user, I know m (m <=n) of them should be marked for the user (stored in a database with `userid|itemid` table.) while displaying them as HTML list.

What is the most efficient way to do this? I'm using php

We can obviously do this in O(mn) checking each list item against the user history but is there some better way? and can the algorithm change if we know that m << n .

Comment: I posted it as an algorithm problem so I don't think 'trying' is really relevant when I'm writing what algorithm I could think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:  Name the variables populating the checkboxes intelligently so that you can reference them by the id of the item.

Step 2:  Pull (m) items out of the database.

Step 3:  Loop through (m), and for each item in (m), mark that checkbox as 'checked'.

O(m) result.